# Evaluate each of the numeric expressions: $\sqrt{(-3)}$, $\sqrt{3}$, $\sqrt{-3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Need help breaking down and understanding the concept to get answer.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Cameron Buie:  I think OP thought the parentheses around one of the $-3$'s were important, so should not be removed from the title.  Otherwise the first and third are the same.

Comment: I've removed the tag complex-numbers again, since I don't think this question is about complex numbers.

Comment: @Ross: I just edited the tags.

Answer (score 1):

In the real numbers, there are two square roots of $3$, which are approximately $\pm 1.732.$  You can check this with your calculator.  In the reals, there are not square roots of $-3$, whether you put parentheses around it or not.  In the complex numbers, there are two square roots of $-3$, which are $\pm \sqrt 3 i$.  In the complex numbers $i$ is defined as (one of the) square roots of $-1$, so if you square either $+\sqrt 3 i$ or $-\sqrt 3 i$ you get $-3.$

Comment: As far as I know, while the equation $x^2 = a$  has two solutions for $a > 0$, $\sqrt{a}$ is defined as the positive square root, not both. This only applies when working in $\mathbb{R}$, since in $\mathbb{C}$ you can't distinguish positive and negative.

Comment: @JavierBadia:  Originally the title of the question spelled out "square root of 3".  I agree that when we use the square root sign we take the positive one.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit

We have $i^{2}=-1.$ Taking square root of both sides, we get $\sqrt{i^{2}}= \sqrt{-1} \Rightarrow i=\sqrt{-1}$.

Hence, $\sqrt{-3}=\sqrt{3\times(-1)}=\sqrt{3}\times\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{3}i$.